# Nginx redirecting for specific list of arguments

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a list of some obsolete arguments in URLs.

```
arg1
arg2
arg3
...
argn
```

I need to redirect any of the request having any of those  arguments in the query part of the link, to a specific site.

```
/page.html?arg1=sxx&arg2=uuu  -> http://xxx.x.xxx.x
/page.php?arg3=  -> http://xxx.x.xxx.x
/dir/dir/page/?arg2=111&& argn=xyyyy  -> http://xxx.x.xxx.x
/page.html (is not redirected but matched to other existing rules in nginx)
```

Any idea how to express it nicely? For some reasons location has no arguments to be matched by regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the argument order is deterministic, you can test multiple regular expressions against the $request_uri variable.

The `map` directive can be used to list multiple rules and destinations.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $redirect {
    default                          0;
    ~^/page\.html\?arg1=sxx&arg2=uuu http://xxx.x.xxx.x;
    ~^/page\.php\?arg3=              http://xxx.x.xxx.x;
    ...
}

server {
    ...
    if ($redirect) {
        return 301 $redirect;
    }
```

You will of course want to improve the regular expressions above, by inserting gaps (`.*`) and word boundaries (`\b`).

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for the `map` directive, and [this note](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.