# Redirect 301 Nginx with query string "?amp" - AMP Nginx Redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make a rewrite rule in Nginx,  that contains "?amp" at the end of the request, like this:

```
From 
http://mywebsite.com/path1/lalala?amp  

To 
http://mywebsite.com/path1/lalala
```

It's a redirect 301.
I tried some rules, but they do not work, I get many redirects (looping).

Examples that did not work.

```
rewrite ^/path1/lalala.*? htttp://mywebsite.com/path1/lalala? permanent;

Or

rewrite ^/path1/lalala.*? /path1/lalala? permanent;
```

I think the problem is in the query string "?amp".
Do you know how to do this redirect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx redirecting for specific list of arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843692/nginx-redirecting-for-specific-list-of-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

```
rewrite ^/path1/lalala[^?]*\? /path1/lalala permanent;
```

`[^?]*` matches zero or more characters that aren't a question mark, so we make sure to start stripping at the first one.

Then, importantly, the `?` *has to be escaped* with a backslash because in regexes they have a special meaning.